# Access Totals Query Not Necessarily Returning First Record

Tags: ms-access

I have a table of data like this:

```
id  user_id  A  B  C
=====================
1   15       1  2  3
2   15       1  2  5
3   20       1  3  9
4   20       1  3  7
```

I need to remove duplicate user ids and keep the record that sorts lowest when sorting by A then B then C.  So using the above table, I set up a temp query (qry_temp) that simply does the sort--first on user_id, then on A, then on B, then on C.  It returns the following:

```
id user_id  A  B  C
====================
1  15       1  2  3
2  15       1  2  5
4  20       1  3  7
3  20       1  3  9
```

Then I wrote a Totals Query based on qry_temp that just had user_id (Group By) and then id (First), and I assumed this would return the following:

```
user_id  id
===========
15       1
20       4
```

But it doesn't seem to do that--instead it appears to be just returning the lowest id in a group of duplicate user ids (so I get 1 and 3 instead of 1 and 4).  Shouldn't the Totals query use the order of the query it's based upon?  Is there a property setting in the query that might impact this or another way to get what I need?  If it helps, here is the SQL:

```
SELECT qry_temp.user_id, First(qry_temp.ID) AS FirstOfID
FROM qry_temp
GROUP BY qry_temp.user_id;
```

Comment: I'm reviewing this now:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208190

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a different type of query, for example:

```
SELECT tmp.id,
       tmp.user_id,
       tmp.a,
       tmp.b,
       tmp.c
FROM   tmp
WHERE  (( ( tmp.id ) IN (SELECT TOP 1 id
                         FROM   tmp t
                         WHERE  t.user_id = tmp.user_id
                         ORDER  BY t.a,
                                   t.b,
                                   t.c,
                                   t.id) ));
```

Where tmp is the name of your table. First, Last, Min and Max are not dependent on a sort order. In relational databases, sort orders are quite ephemeral.

Comment: Thanks, Remou--this seems to work, but it's tough to confirm b/c it won't actually let me search or move to the end of the recordset.  There are 45,000 records in the source query (tmp), so it's big but not huge--this query you suggested returns results, but if I search on a user_id it just goes to "Not responding".  Same thing if I try to move to the last record.  Any suggestions on improving performance?  Thanks again.

Comment: Are you basing the query on a table or query? It would be best to use a table. Have you got indexes on the table?

Comment: I'm basing it on a query b/c I had filtered out some records.  I could do the filter after though and base it on a table.  I'll try that.  I do have indexes, though none that I placed myself--I guess Access defaulted some fields to indexes.  I imagine the indexes help, but unfortunately there are only a couple fields that would qualify as index values.

Comment: Wow, that really helped @Remou--thanks.  Unfortunately this query does still return some duplicate user ids...not many (maybe 15 in a 2,000 record sample)--any idea why that would happen?

Comment: ID is always unique, but user_id can have duplicates, and I'm trying to get rid of all the duplicate user_ids by taking the first of any group of duplicate ids based on that sort.  I'll try to get an example.

Comment: @Remou--it looks like I am getting duplicates if all of a, b and c are the same (so user_id, a, b, and c are all the same in both records).  And I now see why--for that last "t.id" I had "t.user_id" (just a typo), so then both records looked the same in the sort--I just changed it and it worked flawlessly!  I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Access SQL will return more than one record with Top when there are matches, so you need to stick a unique value on the end or the sort, as you have found. Glad it worked for you.